How to remove extra tabs from Name field in abap from kna1 table
I'm stuck in a requirement where I generated an ABAP report in which there is a selection screen which accepts kunnr as input from kna1 table and, based on that, I'm fetching details of kna1 table like name1, name2, land1, etc.
When I'm giving the customer number in selection screen and debugging it.
I'm getting # in name1 and name2 in the internal table of kna1.
My task is to remove those tabs if there is any tab (#) in name1 and name2. I have to remove it and make it as normal.
For example:
name1: Peter##
name2: ###Henry
Then expected output should be:
name1: Peter
name2: Henry
Could anyone help me in getting it corrected?
I tried to remove those extra tabs, which are coming as # in debugging mode, but I'm not able to remove it.

This question is similar to: How to replace or delete double hash (##) in string?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also similar to Replacing special characters with space.

In the ABAP debugger, non-printable characters like U+000D, U+000A, U+0009 (tab) are displayed like #. See the previously mentioned questions and answers how to replace or delete non-printable characters. For information, this is the way to define the tab character in ABAP: DATA(tab) = |\t| (ABAP >=7.40).
